# Mathcad using Odesolve function $y'+2xy=x\cdot e^{-x^2}$

Tags: mathcad

I just can't use the Odesolve function for this equation: $$y'+2xy=x\cdot e^{-x^2}$$ If anyone could help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Welcome to the site !*

This is not a site where anyone would do your homawork for you. You need to show what you did and explain where you are stuck.

As a welcoming gift, I shall give you a hint for the equation
$$y'+2xy=x\, e^{-x^2}$$

Let $y=z \, e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Sorry and thanks Sir, but I managed to solve it on my own, made a silly mistake with defining the Odesolve function. I was new to this Mathcad, solving by hand seemed even easier at that point.